# Want to resume video in onMovedToScrapHeap

Tags: android, android-video-player

This is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listview;
    CustomListAdapter adapter;
    private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public static int currentItem;
    public static ArrayList<String> videoLIst;
    public static MediaController mediaController ;
    boolean pauseOnScroll = true;
    boolean pauseOnFling = true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
        videoLIst = new ArrayList<String>();
         mediaController = new MediaController(MainActivity.this); 
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        //adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, videoLIst);
        // Set video link (mp4 format )
        listview.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, videoLIst));

      listview.setRecyclerListener(new RecyclerListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMovedToScrapHeap(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               VideoView videoView = (VideoView)view.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
                    if(videoView != null)
                    {
                    videoView.stopPlayback();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        videoView.start();
                    }
                }

    });

    }
    static class ViewHolderItem {

                TextView textViewItem;
                VideoView video;
                ProgressBar progressbar;
            }

    public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Activity activity;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private ArrayList<String> videoList;

        public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> videoList) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.videoList = videoList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return videoList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int location) {
            return videoList.get(location);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

            if (inflater == null)
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolder.video = (VideoView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
            viewHolder.progressbar = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress);

            viewHolder.textViewItem =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txvposition);

            viewHolder.textViewItem.setText("Video"+position);

            mediaController.setAnchorView(viewHolder.video);
            Log.d("video url inadapter:", ""+videoLIst.toString());
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoList.get(position));
            viewHolder.video.setMediaController(mediaController);
            viewHolder.video.setVideoURI(uri);
            //viewHolder.video.start();

            viewHolder.video.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                    viewHolder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewHolder.video.start();
                }
            });
            viewHolder.video.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Log.d("BUFFRRING START", "On_InFO");

                    if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START == what) {
                        viewHolder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Log.d("BUFFRRING START", "" + what);
                    }
                    if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END == what) {
                        viewHolder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Log.d("BUFFRRING END", "" + what);
                    }
                    if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START == what) {
                        viewHolder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Log.d("RENDERING END", "" + what);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            viewHolder.video.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Log.d("Error", "------>error" + what + "/" + extra);
                    if (extra != 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Can't Play Video",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });

            int pos;
            pos=viewHolder.video.getCurrentPosition();
            Log.d("current item position:",""+pos);
             convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


        }
        else{

            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();

         }

        return convertView;
      }    
    }

}
```

I want functionality like vine app, when Video visible in listview it plays and when I scroll up listview and It becomes invisible it pauses and when I scroll down It again resume play from where it stopped;my problem is that when I scroll up listview video is paused but when I scroll down it not resume from where it paused. How I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListView: Prevent a view from recycling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751707/listview-prevent-a-view-from-recycling)